# Imshow in large arrays

Tags: python, imshow

I'm trying to use `Imshow` to make a plot from arrays of `~97000` elements each. I've read the info on the webpage of numpy and also read some examples, I've tried them and it works, but when I try to use my large arrays I have a problem related to the memory that the function uses. Does anyone have an idea on what can be going wrong?

Cheers.

Comment: Share the code that you've tried and then it'll be helpful. Please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting a quesiton.

Comment: Please also add your example results if you can/may. I cant, maybe you can try to draw the resulting scheme of images(?) you'd like to see as output.

Comment: Try using numpy.memmap when dealing with large arrays...